# Importing .dll with Unity and HoloLens2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, hololens, mrtk

I tried to develop an augmented reality application with Unity for HoloLens2. Therefore we need to connect the application with an external controller from fischertechnik. I tried to import the .dll which is needed into unity. There are no errors in Visual Studio, in the Unity Player everything works fine and the application connects with the controller. But if we try to build it, a bunch of errors occur:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx27v.png). Would be nice if someone could help! Thanks

Settings:

[Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbMhV.png)

[Player Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QoDx.png)

[DLLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56jn6.png)

Comment: The Target version of Net/Core is not loaded on the machine you are using to compile.  So you either have to change the target version in VS project or install the missing version of Net/Core.

Comment: @jdweng the problem we have is that the dll only runs with .NetFramework 4.6, I don't know in which ways we can change the settings or if unity or the HoloLens2 is even able to work with .NetFramework 4.6

Comment: That is dangerous only with 4.6!!!  There are bugs in Net with deployment to targets especially to core before 4.7.2.  I would try to target HoloLens2 to Net 4.7.2 or later.  It should work.  I don't know any reasons that you shouldn't be able to move forward.  Make sure you do a Clean build.

Comment: @jdweng so it would be helpful to set up all dll files for 4.7.2? I updated the question with a few pictures of the settings we chose for developing. There shouldn't be any problems I guess...

Comment: Definitely since you are using CORE.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, I will work on this!

Comment: Suggestion: You can paste the errors in a text code field, that way could be easier to follow and to be found later.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Change your minimum UWP setting to **10.0.16299** or later (I'd choose at least 18362 for HoloLens 2)

More info:

HoloLens applications are UWP apps, so you will need to make sure that your libraries are supported in UWP.

From the errors you list, the problems come from System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.dll. Per the System.Reactive.Windows.Threading project at https://github.com/dotnet/reactive , the supported platforms for v5.x include **UWP 10.0.16299** with a note that "Support for UWP 10.0 has been removed"

Looking at your Build Settings, your app's minimum UWP target is 10.0.10240.0 (aka UWP 10.0).

This specific error should go away if you upgrade your minimum UWP setting to 10.0.16299.

16299 was the first UWP version to support .Net Standard 2.0 and so is a common base level for managed UWP apps. 16299 shipped as the Fall Creators Update in November 2017, several years and versions before the [HoloLens 2 shipped in 2019 with Build 18362.1039](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-release-notes#windows-holographic-version-1903---november-2019-update).